# Highcharts datagrouped updating column lose visible integrity

Tags: highcharts

In a project, I'm using something very similar to this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z3vhg/

The code for this dynamically updating data-grouped columns chart is the following:

```
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
    chart : {
        type: 'column',
        events : {
            load : function() {

                // set up the updating of the chart each second
                var series = this.series[0];
                setInterval(function() {
                    var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                    y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
                    series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        offset: 30
    },
    rangeSelector: {
        buttons: [{
            count: 1,
            type: 'minute',
            text: '1M'
        }, {
            count: 5,
            type: 'minute',
            text: '5M'
        }, {
            type: 'all',
            text: 'All'
        }],
        inputEnabled: false,
        selected: 2
    },

    title : {
        text : 'Live random data'
    },

    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series : [{
        name : 'Random data',
        dataGrouping: {
            groupPixelWidth: 60
            },
        data : (function() {
            // generate an array of random data
            var data = [], time = (new Date()).getTime(), i;

            for( i = -999; i <= 0; i++) {
                data.push([
                    time + i * 1000,
                    Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
                ]);
            }
            return data;
        })()
    }]
});
```

The problem can be observed in the fiddle above: as the data updates and adds new points, the first point on the x axis is shifted, but since data grouping is used, the column remains there but gives the impression that the first column value is actually changing...

Any help appreciated, as it may be a weird combination issue.

Comment: Obviously, using **false** to prevent shifting when adding  point clears this issue, but I'd like not to use that

Comment: But first and last columns are changing - when adding new point, grouped point value is increasing, and when removing last point (from grouped point in jsfiddle example) - value is decreasing.

Comment: I've noticed in your example that the navigator is not functioning properly

Comment: I know the behavior makes sense once you know that datagrouping is used but from an end-user pov... this sounds odd and makes you think PAST data is actually refreshing.

Comment: Another issue now: in the meantime I tried to set the shifting to false on the chart, see http://jsfiddle.net/Z3vhg/1/ 
The problem now is that it works as expected whon vieweng the ALL range, but the chart still shifts when viewing the 1min or 5min ranges...
Any way to fully disable the shifting...